# Delphi 10.4 TbannerAD return error 3 in test mode

Tags: delphi

I want to add an ad display for my app
i create Ad unit in `https://apps.admob.com/`
i set TestMode and AdUnitID (Ad unit ID) in my application.
i add

```
<meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value=""/>
```

<---My APP ID is here

(I could not find the app ID settings inside the Delphi IDE That's why I added it to the manifest file manually)

but when i call LoadAd (want show AD) (test mode is active) get Error 3.

Comment: "I could not find the app ID settings inside the Delphi IDE". http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_the_AdMob_Service

Comment: this is AdUnitID , There is no explanation about APP ID

Comment: Sorry, yes.. the way you have provided the App ID is correct. If you have Delphi 10.4, I suggest ensuring you have 10.4.2 and use TFirebaseBannerAd instead (or at least try it)

Comment: @DaveNottage thanks, but i khow TFirebaseBannerAd only work at platform IOS

Comment: Sorry again.. I forgot it was iOS only

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be a Delphi issue but an AdMob error which seems to be that there just are not ads available to show.

Comment: Do not even have ads to display the test? So how do other people's apps I use show ads?

Comment: Whatever your situation, go and research this particular error outside the Delphi realm and you will see how others encounter this error and and what the reason for it was.